# RestClient POST to API doesn't work in Release Build

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2015

I have a somewhat weird problem that I'm unsure on how to fix. The goal is to post to an API using RestClient. This works fine within Debug mode within Visual Studio. However, when I build the project for Release and open the .exe directly. The POST returns a statuscode of 0.

Here is some snippets of code I used. Still a bit new at this. Thanks for the help.

```
var url = "https://testurl.com";


//ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

// create a new RestSharp client
var client = new RestClient(url);

try
{
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
    {
        RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json
    };

    request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    MessageBox.Show(url);
    var response = client.Execute(request);

    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(JToken.Parse(response.Content));
        ProcessResponse(response.Content);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Request returned a status other than OK" + Environment.NewLine + "StatusCode: " + response.StatusCode.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + response.Content + Environment.NewLine + "The certificate used was " + cert.ToString(), "Error");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "There was a problem.");
}
```

Comment: if the command line exit code is 0 then your code is working fine. [looks here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194959(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: if you want to make sure its working fine , add some logging in your code and run the exe to verify the http status code

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to mention it's a WPF application. I have a messagebox that displays "Request returned a status other than OK" when the StatusCode isn't right. That's what comes up when I run the exe.

Comment: Ok What was the html status code returned?

Comment: 0. When used in Debug mode, it works as intended. I get a StatusCode.Created. But when opening after it's built, straight from the release folder. I get 0. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MichaelArvelo sounds like the Post may not be returning anything. If this is your service, make sure to return Ok(myModel). Other than that, if you could post the service method code, that may shed some more light on the subject.